# Update attributes to an object that is the value in a dictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

I want to update the attributes to an object that is in a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> test = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
test.Add("first", new MyObject { myString = "test_1", myInt = 123 }

Class MyObject
{ 
    public string myString { get; set; }
    public int myInt {get; set;}
    public int myInt2 {get; set;}
}
```

Let's say MyObject has 3 attributes, a string, and 2 ints.  Now I search a text file and find the third int value, how do I add it to the dictionary with the key?

Am I going about this the right way? perhaps there is something other than a dictionary to use?

Essentially I have a key, and I need to add multiple values for it as I get them.

Please let me know how I can clarify.

Comment: Sounds to me like, there is different problem you are trying to solve... Could you please try to frame the question, with what might be the real problem you are trying to solve? In other words, not sure what is the context of your question "Am I going about **this** the right way?"

Comment: you will get an exception when you try to add multiple values with the same key into a Dictionary.

Comment: @Vikas Gupta.  Artem O had the solution for me.  I'm going to try and work on the real problem I am trying to solve with this knowledge, and if I hit another dead end I'll make a new, more detailed post with the real problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that MyObject looks like:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public int Int1 { get; set; }
    public int Int2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can update attributes to an object in a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> test = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
test.Add("first", new MyObject {StringProperty = "test_1", Int1 = 123});

test["first"].Int2 = 321;
```

Regarding your approach.
As commented to original post, you cannot store one key with different values in Dictionary object. So your choice to have data object, which holds all the data and updated when new data comes, is pretty legal.